# Is there anyway to convert an existing DB Schema (mssql) to a GraphQL schema?

Tags: c#, graphql

Right now, I'm using .NET core to code for GraphQL. I've just started using GraphQL for the last 6 months. I'm searching for a way to convert a DB schema to GraphQL schema. Somewhat in the lines of Hasura, SwitchQL but for C#. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Why wouldn't you use Hasura to expose GraphQL and consume that end point via .NET?